# Getting Error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16.0"

Tags: java

I  want to convert the cell value into `int` value so i am trying following code:

```
for (int chk1 = 1; chk1 < m; chk1++ ) {
   int intCounter = Integer.parseInt( cells.checkCell(chk1,0).getValue().toString() );
}
```

But it is accepting only the string format if there is any number then it is giving me

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

How can I avoid this? Is there any way to convert all data into integer or into String or vice versa?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is the ".0" bit. `Integer.parseInt` only allows digits so the decimal point is illegal, hence the `NumberFormatException`.

You should make sure that your input really is an integer (i.e. "16"), or if you actually want to allow decimals then use `Double.parseDouble` or `Float.parseFloat`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Double.intValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try and see what exactly is being fed to the `parseInt`

```
System.out.println(cells.checkCell(chk1,0).getValue().toString());
```

or log it.

See if the value you're parsing is valid per Cameron's answer.

Comment: The exception *already* tellls you exactly what is being fed to `parseInt()`, it's `16.0`!

Comment: I am new here.. Agree that 16.0 wont get parsed. But where do we see that the input was 16.0? I am just not able to figure out where.

Comment: @Schock: the exception message is in the title (and *only* there, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

@Cameron Skinner has given you an exact hint how you can get rid of this exception by using `double` or `float`. But if you really want to play with `Integer` you can do

```
for( int chk1 = 1 ; chk1 < m ; chk1++ ) {
   int intCounter = (int)cells.checkCell(chk1,0).getValue();
}
```

Comment: If it can be cast to an int, you don't need the toString and parseInt()